# Can I use post method in requests lib on this Binance site?

Tags: python-3.x, post, python-requests

Here is the site:
https://www.binance.com/ru/futures-activity/leaderboard?type=myProfile&tradeType=PERPETUAL&encryptedUid=E921F42DCD4D9F6ECC0DFCE3BAB1D11A

I am parsing the positions of the trader by selenium, but today realize, that I can use post method.

Here  is what "NETWORK" shows:
[image: network]

Here is response preview:

[image]

I have no experience with post method of requests, I tried this, but doesn't work.

```
import requests

hd = {'accept':"*/*",'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36'}

ses = requests.Session()
c = ses.post('https://www.binance.com/bapi/futures/v1/public/future/leaderboard/getOtherPosition',headers=hd)
print(c.text)
```

Output is:

```
{"code":"000002","message":"illegal parameter","messageDetail":null,"data":null,"success":false}
```

Can someone help me to do it, please? Is it real?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working as POST method

```
import requests

url='https://www.binance.com/bapi/futures/v1/public/future/leaderboard/getOtherPerformance'
headers= {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "x-trace-id": "4c3d6fce-a2d8-421e-9d5b-e0c12bd2c7c0",
    "x-ui-request-trace": "4c3d6fce-a2d8-421e-9d5b-e0c12bd2c7c0"
}

payload = {"encryptedUid":"E921F42DCD4D9F6ECC0DFCE3BAB1D11A","tradeType":"PERPETUAL"}

req=requests.post(url,headers=headers,json=payload).json()
#print(req)
for item in req['data']:
    roi = item['value']
    print(roi)
```

**Output:**

```
-0.023215
-91841.251668
0.109495
390421.996614
-0.063094
-266413.73955621
0.099181
641189.24407088
0.072079
265977.556474
-0.09197
-400692.52138279
-0.069988
-469016.33171481
0.0445
292594.20440128
```

Answer (score 2):

I am used [Curlconverter](https://curlconverter.com/), and it helped me a lot! Here is the working code:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.binance.com',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ja;q=0.6,ko;q=0.5,zh-CN;q=0.4,zh;q=0.3',
    'bnc-uuid': '0202c537-8c2b-463a-bdef-33761d21986a',
    'clienttype': 'web',
    'csrftoken': 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e',
    'device-info': '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',
    'fvideo-id': '3214483f88c0abbba34e5ecf5edbeeca1e56e405',
    'lang': 'ru',
    'origin': 'https://www.binance.com',
    'referer': 'https://www.binance.com/ru/futures-activity/leaderboard?type=myProfile&tradeType=PERPETUAL&encryptedUid=E921F42DCD4D9F6ECC0DFCE3BAB1D11A',
    'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="101", "Google Chrome";v="101"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/101.0.4951.67 Safari/537.36',
    'x-trace-id': 'e9d5223c-5d71-4834-8563-c253a1fc3ae8',
    'x-ui-request-trace': 'e9d5223c-5d71-4834-8563-c253a1fc3ae8',
}

json_data = {
    'encryptedUid': 'E921F42DCD4D9F6ECC0DFCE3BAB1D11A',
    'tradeType': 'PERPETUAL',
}

response = requests.post('https://www.binance.com/bapi/futures/v1/public/future/leaderboard/getOtherPosition', headers=headers, json=json_data)
print(response.text)
```

So output now is:

```
{"code":"000000","message":null,"messageDetail":null,
"data":{
"otherPositionRetList":[{"symbol":"ETHUSDT","entryPrice":1985.926527932,"markPrice":2013.57606795,"pnl":41926.93300012,"roe":0.05492624,"updateTime":[2022,5,22,15,35,39,358000000],"amount":1516.370,"updateTimeStamp":1653233739358,"yellow":true,"tradeBefore":false},{"symbol":"KSMUSDT","entryPrice":80.36574159583,"markPrice":79.46000000,"pnl":-1118.13799285,"roe":-0.01128900,"updateTime":[2022,5,16,11,0,5,608000000],"amount":1234.5,"updateTimeStamp":1652698805608,"yellow":false,"tradeBefore":false},{"symbol":"IMXUSDT","entryPrice":0.9969444089129,"markPrice":0.97390429,"pnl":-13861.75961996,"roe":-0.02365747,"updateTime":[2022,5,22,15,57,3,329000000],"amount":601636,"updateTimeStamp":1653235023329,"yellow":true,"tradeBefore":false},{"symbol":"MANAUSDT","entryPrice":1.110770201096,"markPrice":1.09640000,"pnl":-6462.14960820,"roe":-0.05242685,"updateTime":[2022,5,21,16,6,2,291000000],"amount":449691,"updateTimeStamp":1653149162291,"yellow":false,"tradeBefore":false},{"symbol":"EOSUSDT","entryPrice":1.341744945184,"markPrice":1.35400000,"pnl":-4572.78323455,"roe":-0.09051004,"updateTime":[2022,5,22,11,47,48,542000000],"amount":-373134.3,"updateTimeStamp":1653220068542,"yellow":true,"tradeBefore":false},{"symbol":"BTCUSDT","entryPrice":29174.44207538,"markPrice":30015.10000000,"pnl":-173841.33354801,"roe":-0.47613317,"updateTime":[2022,5,21,15,13,0,252000000],"amount":-206.792,"updateTimeStamp":1653145980252,"yellow":false,"tradeBefore":false},{"symbol":"DYDXUSDT","entryPrice":2.21378804417,"markPrice":2.11967778,"pnl":-48142.71521969,"roe":-0.08879676,"updateTime":[2022,5,18,16,40,18,654000000],"amount":511556.5,"updateTimeStamp":1652892018654,"yellow":false,"tradeBefore":false}],"updateTime":[2022,5,16,11,0,5,608000000],"updateTimeStamp":1652698805608},"success":true}
```